# Need to have button change text when clicked, then change back when outside click

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a "Quit" button that changes text based on a variable. When clicked, the variable increases by one, and the application quits when the var is 2.

```
public static int QuitVar = 0;

        private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QuitVar = QuitVar + 1;

            if (QuitVar == 0)
            {
                quitToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Quit";
            }

            if (QuitVar == 1)
            {
                quitToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Really?";
            }

            if (QuitVar == 2)
            {
                QuitVar = 0;
                Application.Exit();
            }
```

I would like QuitVar to change back to 0 when the user clicks outside the button, so the button text is "quit". Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: What API are you using? WPF? WinForm? ASP.NET? UWP?

Comment: the requirement/design is bad.

Comment: @DourHighArch Windows Forms.

Comment: @LeiYang Noted, how would you do it?

Comment: i don't want to do it because the requirement is bad and the user will not like  this product.

Comment: @LeiYang thats neat, however I don't think users will really care about the code in the project if it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many places a user could click that aren't the Quit button.  What might be easier is to detect when the mouse leaves the Quit button with the [`MouseLeave` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx).

By going to the Control properties (I used a Button here), and Events (the lighting symbol), then double-clicking inside the MouseLeave event, it will generate a template event handler method for you:
[image]

Inside that event handler, set your text and `QuitVar` appropriately:

```
private void quitToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuitVar = 0;
    quitToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Quit";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will do it.

Comment: This won't detect a click outside the quit button, just that the mouse has moved off it.

Comment: @ainwood True.  But it still solves the problem.  The state is reset before the user can even click outside the button.

Comment: But if the button is small, any slight movement will reset it. I personally would find this pretty annoying.

Comment: @ainwood This is true.  The whole design is questionable.  Once a user realises it's going to require 2 clicks, they will just double-click.  Better would be a confirmation dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom ToolstripMenuItem, and override the WndProc Method.
The override can capture the windows messages, and notify when the click is not on the item.  The following code is adapted from code to close a form if the user clicks outside it, but it should suit your purposes.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Function to capture if the user clicks outside of the control, in which case need to close this form.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        // if click outside dialog -> Close Dlg
        if (m.Msg == 0x86) //0x86 = NativeConstants.WM_NCACTIVATE
        {
            if (this.Visible)
            {
                if (!this.RectangleToScreen(this.DisplayRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position))
                    QuitVar = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```